# Define is not a function using SystemJS

Tags: javascript, angular, amd, systemjs

I'm using SystemJS as module system in Angular 2. This is my `index.html` file

```
<html>

  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Home</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">

    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <!-- Routing -->
    <script src="angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- ArcGIS -->
    <script src="//js.arcgis.com/3.15/"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        map: {
          esri: '//js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri'
        },
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });

      System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <app>Loading map...</app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

[image]

this error come up because I'm using SystemJs instead of AMD and define is then not recognized properly. Do you have any suggestion?

EDIT:

Added the following configuration:

```
<script>
      System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            map: {
              esri: '//js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri'
            },
            meta: {
              'esri/*': {
                format: 'amd'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });

      System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

but still getting the same error

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1073

Comment: Have you tried loading any other AMD modules with systemjs? This could possibly be an issue with the esri library.

Comment: No honestly I didn't tried yet